# Adding a helper function to make the whole <th> tag clickable for sorting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, helper, link-to

I created a def sortable () in the /helpers folder in Ruby on Rails. I have a custom link_to aka `<%= sortable , "name" , "Track" %>` I would like to use in the `<th>` of my table but I cannot get it to wrap the whole tag.

I have tried passing in an jQuery .on("click")passing the <%= sortable "name" inside the `<th>` as an href and data-link.

```
<thead>
       <tr class="tr-header">
 **THIS*** <th class='track'> <%= sortable "name", "Track" %> </th>

          <th class='delete'>DELETE TRACK</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
```

The helper method

```
module TracksHelper
    def sortable(column_name, title = nil) 
      title ||= column_name.titleize
      direction = column_name == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      link_to title, { :sort => column_name, :direction => direction }, {:class => "fas-fa-sort"}
    end
end
```

The controller

```
format.html {
        pdog = params[:sort] == nil ? "" : params[:sort] + " " + params[:direction]
        if (@current_user.admin != true)
        # only for my tracks, unless we are admin
        @tracks = Track.where(:user_id => 
            @current_user.id).order(pdog).joins(:user)
       else

     # /index?approved=false
     action  = params['approved']
      if action == 'false'
       # test it in rails c   for quicker trial and error
       @tracks = Track.where(approved: false).joins(:user).order(pdog)            
      else

     @tracks = Track.joins(:user).order(pdog)
    end
  end
}
```

I just want the whole `<th>` to use the <%= sortable, "name, "Track" %> that I created and I would like to know what is best practice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use raw() at first then switched to using a partial.

```
<%= render partial: "track_th", locals: {column_name: "name", title: "Track"} %>
```

then created another view.html.erb and passed in the helper method and html

```
<% title ||= column_name.titleize %>
<% direction = column_name == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc" %>



<th>
  <span class="trackTable_th_span">
    <%= link_to "?sort="+column_name+"&direction="+direction do %>
    <%= title %><i class="fas fa-sort"></i>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</th>
```

I also used the same partial in a different view so I had to change the url as follows

```
 <table id="myAccountTable">
          <thead>
              <tr class="tr-header">
               <%= render partial: "/tracks/track_th", locals: {column_name: "name", title: "TRACK "} %>

                <th class='delete'>DELETE TRACK</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
```

I got help from someone fyi but I thought I would share the answer if anyone gets stuck trying to make `<th>` clickable in Rails